# Android activity unresponsive until back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, input, oncreate

Below is the oncreate to my activity. My issue is that when the activity is started it is completely unresponsive until I press the back button. Once I press the back button it works perfectly.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_packs);
    count = 0;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null || !equals("")){
        name = extras.getString("name");
    }
    else{name="PackActivity";}


    //getActionBar().setTitle(name);  
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.navigation_bar_colour_image);
    //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(name);

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.hide();
    database = new DataObjectDataSource(this.getApplicationContext());
    //load all the packs from the DB
    packs = loadPacks();
    //make the request for GetPacks
    sortArrayById();

    if(isOnline(this)) {
        HTTPRequest.getHTTPRequest(HTTPRequest.getPacksURL, this);
    }
    else{
        dialog("No internet connection available","their is limited functionality available in offline mode",1);
    }


    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.packGrid);

    adapter = new PackGridAdapter(this, getApplicationContext(), packs);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    System.out.println(" pack_ids ");
}
```

I have included the dialog function as the unresponsiveness comes after it have been dismissed.

```
public boolean dialog(String mes,String message,int type){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Add the buttons
    if(type==2){
        builder.setMessage(message)
        .setTitle(mes);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               });
    }
    // Create the AlertDialog
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    if(type==2){
        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
                // when the task active then close the dialog
                t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Obviously UI tread stops somehow. Did you check after which line of code UI thread stops?

Comment: I have just figured it out haha. Typical! The dialog function being called wasn't dismissing the dialog properly. Thanks for looking anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Things:

1st confirm that your `ActionBar` code is working (comment the `actionbar` part to make sure that is not culprit here) to see if the activity is responsive or not

If the 1st doesn't work, and even after commenting `ActionBar` activity is unresponsive .. then

2nd comment these lines:

```
if(isOnline(this)) {
    HTTPRequest.getHTTPRequest(HTTPRequest.getPacksURL, this);
}
else{
    dialog("No internet connection available","their is limited functionality available in offline mode",1);
}
```

I suspect you're doing some network operation on your UI Thread, that could be the cause of Activity not Responding or it must have something to do with the `dialog` method you're using. If you show that method code, it could lead further to diagnose.

Comment: I've just figured it out. The dialog function I have wasn't dismissing the dialog properly. You were on the right lines though. Thanks for looking.